# Disabling dynamic web api for certain services

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I downloaded the ASP Boilerplate template and I am trying to disable the creation of certain dynamic WebAPIs. I read the documentation at https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API  yet I cannot find where to disable this in the template. I am using the NET Core + Angular4 template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the attribute **[RemoteService(false)]** to disable creation of dynamic web api of an application service. Also you can use this attribute on methods of application services.

```
 [RemoteService(false)]
 public interface IRoleAppService : IAsyncCrudAppService<RoleDto, int, PagedResultRequestDto, CreateRoleDto, RoleDto>
 {
        Task<ListResultDto<PermissionDto>> GetAllPermissions();
 }
```

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API#enabledisable

---

While [RemoteService] is the easiest way to disable it, you can use the below code for advanced actions.

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().DynamicApiControllerBuilder
    .ForAll<IApplicationService>(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "app")
    .ForMethods(builder =>
    {
        if (builder.Method.IsDefined(typeof(MyIgnoreApiAttribute)))
        {
            builder.DontCreate = true;
        }
    })
    .Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the aspnetzero template which uses EF Core.  Core uses a slightly different Configuration Module found here:

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/AspNet-Core#application-services-as-controllers

I wanted to use the entity CRUD methods dynamically created but didn't want to expose the delete and update methods.  So, I just overrode them in the application service class and added the `[RemoteService(False)]` attribute to the overridden methods. This prevents them from being generated in the API.